BigQuery JSON Extract Only Returns Nulls
Have been trying to get JSON_EXTRACT or JSON_VALUE working but keeps pulling in nulls
{"$email": {"value": "ddd@gmail.com", "updated_at_ms": 1721139567246}, "$displayName": {"value": "anon anon", "updated_at_ms": 1721139567247}, "$attConsentStatus": {"value": "denied", "updated_at_ms": 1721139678931}, "$firebaseAppInstanceId": {"value": "123", "updated_at_ms": 1721139566741}}
I am simply trying to pull the email value out and have tried a variety of combinations but it always comes back as null
I have tried the below and also have tried playing around the with extract array functions but not sure what to do
JSON_EXTRACT(reserved_subscriber_attributes, '$.email')
JSON_EXTRACT(reserved_subscriber_attributes, '$.email.value')
JSON_EXTRACT(reserved_subscriber_attributes, '$.email[0].value')
Any suggestions?

WITH
  TABLE_DATA AS (
  SELECT
    '{"$email": {"value": "ddd@gmail.com", "updated_at_ms": 1721139567246}, "$displayName": {"value": "anon anon", "updated_at_ms": 1721139567247}, "$attConsentStatus": {"value": "denied", "updated_at_ms": 1721139678931}, "$firebaseAppInstanceId": {"value": "123", "updated_at_ms": 1721139566741}}' AS json_string )
SELECT
  json_string,
  JSON_QUERY(json_string,'$."$email".value'),
  JSON_VALUE(json_string,'$."$email".value')
FROM
  TABLE_DATA

Consider using JSON_QUERY or JSON_VALUE as they are the recommended functions by Google for this purpose. Your first key is "$email", not "email", so, as this has an invalid token for BigQuery, you have to put it between quotes. With that in mind, everything works like a charm.
